# jQuery ajax success and error method args reversed, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arguments, consistency

My jQuery fu is new, so forgive the obvious if this question is indeed that.

jQuery ajax documentation shows error and success defined as follows:

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

This is hosing me a bit consistency-wise as, by default, server-side I return status (200, 401, 404, etc.) along with a JSON encoded response, which could be a json error or success string, array, object and so on.

Basically what is happening is that on success receiving json string (coffeescript)

```
success: (data) ->
  $('#status').html( data )
```

I can print the json response string directly, which is confusing, as the equivalent error version requires me to parse the json string and access the responseText attrib of the data object:

```
error: (data) ->
  $('#status').html( jParse(data.responseText) )
```

So, how can I get client-side to mirror server-side consistency? i.e. respond with json server-side and know that I need parse/access object attrib(s) on client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, in "RESTful" services where success (or otherwise) is indicated in the HTTP status code, you're not supposed to put meaningful content in the HTTP body of an error condition.  Put it in the text of the `40x` error code instead.

Comment: +1, good point, although I believe that is occurring already. My server-side 401, for example, is, "Unauthorized(asJson(i18n('not authorized'))) ", where "not authorized" is a localized message, blah, blah, you need to be logged in to view Foo company content.

Comment: Just looked in firebug, no dice, Play, the framework I am using, sends a 401 with default "Unauthorized" text, so it appears that server-side data is returned in response, not in the status itself

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a bit clearer now:

ajax success's first argument, data, is automatically parsed according to mime type if no dataType param option was set.

That explains why, when handling a json map containing say, an order number, I *do not have to parse it* client-side, could simply refer to `data.orderNum`

On the other hand, there is no such mime type inference on ajax error's first argument, jqXHR, which explains why *I do have to parse* the reply prior to referencing attribs like `data.responseText`.

Probably old hat to many, but good to know what to expect from success/error, was getting double, double quoted string replies and other oddities...